# Global back/next buttons in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have some navigation buttons on an Angular wizard-style webapp. For cosmetic reasons they need to be removed from each partial and added to the root "index.html":

```
<!-- Global navigation buttons for all partials -->
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <button class="btn btn-default" back-action>Back</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" next-action>Next</button>
</div>

<div class="container ng-view ng-cloak">
     <!-- Partials rendered in here, managed by $routeProvider-->
</div>
```

I've attempted to isolate this logic using directives and scope variables to bind the click event and apply target destinations for each partial:

```
.directive('nextAction', ['$location', function($location) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elm) {
            elm.on('click', function () {
               var nextUrl = scope.nextUrl;
               $location.url(nextUrl);
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

The URL's are then defined in each controller:

```
.controller('FirstStepCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.backUrl = '/';
        $scope.nextUrl = '/first/second';
        ...
```

The problem is that `scope.nextUrl` is *undefined* since the directive scope does not inherit the controller scope.

Along with the fact it doesn't currently work, this approach also seems a bit fragile to me since it relies on navigation logic embedded in the controller code.

How might I create better global back/next buttons that dynamically redirect based on the current "page"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a state manager to handle the back and next urls. Relieve the controllers of this responsibility. Then inject it into the directives that handle the back and next buttons.

```
.factory('stateMgr', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var stateMgr = {
        backUrl: '',
        nextUrl: ''
    };

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (nextRoute, lastRoute) {
        // logic in here will look at nextRoute and then set back and next urls
        // based on new route   
        // e.g. stateMgr.backUrl = '/'; stateMgr.nextUrl = '/whatever';
    });

    return stateMgr;
}]);
```

then

```
.controller('FirstStepCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    // do not need to do anything with back/next urls in here
    ...
```

and

```
.directive('nextAction', ['$location', 'stateMgr', function($location, stateMgr) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elm) {
            elm.on('click', function () {
                $location.url(stateMgr.nextUrl);
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ben, this approach does indeed work. I have a concern though, since these variables are now global they can become stale. I had to ensure every controller set both URLs or nulled them out to ensure the user was not jumped two pages (or to the wrong page altogether).


Perhaps there is a way to clear these globals between page changes? This would at least ensure nothing happens unless the back/next globals are set for the current page...

Comment: You need a state manager then. The state manager can keep track of what state you are in using the $routeProvider, and based on that can set what backUrl and nextUrl. Your controllers and directives should ideally not be responsible for knowing where the back and next buttons go. So the state manager could replace the globals guy and listen for route changes and then adjust the back and next url, or back and next could be functions that are called that then check what route is currently active and then navigate wherever based on that.

Comment: I agree. An encapsulated state manager would certainly be more straightforward to maintain than global state. I'm going to mark your answer as the solution since it does actually fix the approach I referred to above. I've since reworked my layout so the navigation buttons can be added back into the partial; which makes the whole thing much tidier but might not be possible for some people.

Comment: Just realised your edits now show the state manager approach. I haven't tested this approach but it looks much cleaner. I could imagine this being a nice generic Angular "state" module, if someone was up to the project...